# Using Fulltext leads to wrong results?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to perform a simple text search.

However, if I use `mysqli_real_escape_string` it makes the program buggy.

I have a Fulltext column `title`, but the functionality does not work in phpMyadmin after I do :

**PhpMyadmin**

```
 - **id|title** 
 - 1|cool boy
 - 2|cool bottle
 - 3|cool guy
 - 4|hot man
```

Here is the rest of my php files :

**file1.php**

```
   //from a form

   $str = $_POST['q'];
   $str=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$str);
   mysqli_query($con,"insert into tbl(title)values($str)");
```

**file2.php**

```
$str = $_GET['q'];

$data = mysqli_query($con,"select * from tbl where match(title)against('$str')");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
   //do stuff . but yields nothing
}
```

How can I properly perform a Fulltext search of my `title` column?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  select * from tbl where title LIKE '%cool%'
```

EDIT: if you wanna do fulltext search then change this

```
  against('cool')
```

to

```
 against('cool' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

In MySQL there are three types of full-text searches:

- boolean search
- natural language search (used by default)
- query expansion search

From MySQL [manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html):

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ea901/2)

EDIT2:

do in file1.php

```
   session_start(); //this will be in very top of your file
   $str = $_POST['q'];
   $_SESSION['str'] = $str;
   $str=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$str);
   mysqli_query($con,"insert into tbl(title)values($str)");
```

in file2.php

```
   session_start(); //this will be in very top of your file
   $str = $_SESSION['str'];
   $data = mysqli_query(.........
```

Comment: makes it too slow need to use fulltext searching

Comment: try this and show the result please `SHOW TABLE STATUS`

Comment: results empty rows `0`

Comment: have you checked the demo and changed what i suggested ?

Comment: if the values are in table why are you showing the insert code ? you wanna select now right ? ,it can be something wrong in your code maybe , this query i gave you works perfect.

Comment: are you fetching the query ?

Comment: 1st i insert a `mysqli_real_escape_string` `$str` into db. Then i get the `$str` i.e `$str="cool"` from user and fetch the results using fulltext.

Comment: you fetching like that ? mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: no sir it will not work GET like that , you should maybe use SESSION instead check my edited answer

Comment: the problem is not that @echo .... problem is `mysqli_real_escape_string` makes the string unidentifieable.

Comment: you must be sure that `$_POST['q']` exist and there is , try echo it and see if there is , otherwise you have problem sending it from your form.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from tbl where title LIKE 'cool%'
```

add only one `%` after your string/variable